# How to pass encryption key inside the replica set pod using MongoDB Enterprise Kubernetes Operator

Tags: mongodb, encryption, enterprise, kubernetes-operator

I have deployed a MongoDB replica set using the [MongoDB Enterprise Kubernetes Operator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-enterprise-kubernetes). The Operator is pointing to the Cloud Manager and I can see the resources in the Cloud Manager dashboard.

So far so good!!!

Now I want to enable encryption at rest using [Local Key Mangement](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/#local-key-management). I have created a key file using openssl but how to pass this key inside the MongoDB replica set pod? Once the file in present inside the pod, I can enable the encryption using the below snippet:

```
additionalMongodConfig:
    security:
      enableEncryption: true
      encryptionKeyFile: "/foo/my_key"
```

Since the replica set pod is being triggered by the Kubernetes operator pod, I am struggling to get this work by volume mounts. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!